# AlertDialog Buttons

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this code and I need to see the positive and negative buttons on a dialog, However I cannot see them. Only the dialog with a title and a message appears. Please help.

Below is my code:

```
 //Ask the user whether they wish to allow the phone permissions
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        builder.setTitle("Phone Permissions");
        builder.setMessage("You need to Give Permissions  to be able to Upload your Picture")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                        finish();
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return;
                    }
                    })
         .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You cannot Upload a photo without Giving Permissions!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.cancel();
                finish();
                return;
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertdialog = builder.create();
        alertdialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer another point of view:

You can just create a custom dialog class in order to give your dialog a custom layout, control everything in a separate class - I find it cleaner and more organized.

**For example, create dialogClass:**

```
public class ProgressDialog extends Dialog {

public ProgressDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);

    setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog); //this is your layout for the dialog

    }
}
```

**And all you need to do is to create dialog instant and call it like this:**

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
progressDialog.show(); // this line shows your dialog
```

And in your dialog class, you can put your logic instead of using a lot of lines of code while using `AlertDialog`

Answer (score 0):

I think your app theme may be causing your buttons in your dialog to not show up because their style matches the color of the dialog. Try clicking where they should appear to see if the buttons are there.

You can also modify the style of your buttons programmatically.

```
Button positiveButton  = alertdialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
// #000000 gives you black
positiveButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
positiveButton.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
```

replace inside of `getButton` with `BUTTON_NEGATIVE` for negative buttons and `BUTTON_NEUTRAL` for neutral buttons.

Comment: Thank you @andy . I changed the dialog theme and the buttons can now show